# Intersection table MySQL

Tags: mysql, intersection

i made three tables, two of them are just information about the customer and the product a third one is just holding the count of the products (more specific info)

two illustrate it! i put an image[Sketch of tables and demanded output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgZb9.png)

Question 1: Is it a good idea doing it like i did?

Question 2: I'm working with PHP, so is it bad, when i try to populate arrays with subinformation, to build up my "demanded" table shown in the attached image?

Thank you very much